# Trying to write to a table from login information in Dreamweaver, all comes up as 1

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, hidden-field

I am building a site using Dreamweaver CS6 as my coding abilities are slightly above minimal.  I was able to get the user login and new user registration working, as well as requiring a login for a page.  Where I'm having difficulty is in trying to attach a user to the entries they put in the other tables.  I've got a table named 'users' that has 'user_login' and 'user_id' as the means of logging into the page.  What I want to do is when a new record is submitted, the button checks 'user_login' against 'user_id' and then puts that numerical value into the 'character_owner' field of the 'characters' table.

Here is the page and the form with the button:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/DLP_RPG.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "0";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 

    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}


?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "PlaySystemForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO characters (character_name1, character_occupation, play_system, character_owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['character_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['character_type1'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['play_system'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "character_input.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_UserLoginForm = "SELECT * FROM users";
$UserLoginForm = mysql_query($query_UserLoginForm, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_UserLoginForm = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserLoginForm);
$totalRows_UserLoginForm = mysql_num_rows($UserLoginForm);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_PlaySystem = "SELECT play_systems.play_system FROM play_systems";
$PlaySystem = mysql_query($query_PlaySystem, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem);
$totalRows_PlaySystem = mysql_num_rows($PlaySystem);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_characters = "SELECT * FROM characters";
$characters = mysql_query($query_characters, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_characters = mysql_fetch_assoc($characters);
$totalRows_characters = mysql_num_rows($characters);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_character_type = "SELECT * FROM character_type1";
$character_type = mysql_query($query_character_type, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_character_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($character_type);
$totalRows_character_type = mysql_num_rows($character_type);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  </head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
    <h1>Starting a new character</h1>
    <p>The first thing to do when starting a new character is to select the play system from a drop down list</p>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="PlaySystemForm" id="PlaySystemForm">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th width="129" scope="row">System:</th>
          <td width="355"><label for="play_system2"></label>
            <select name="play_system" id="play_system2">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_PlaySystem['play_system']?>"><?php echo $row_PlaySystem['play_system']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($PlaySystem);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($PlaySystem, 0);
      $row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Name:</th>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
          <label for="character_name"></label>
          <input name="character_name" type="text" id="character_name" size="25" maxlength="128">
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Type:</th>
          <td><label for="character_type1"></label>
            <select name="character_type1" id="character_type1">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_character_type['character_type1_id']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_character_type['character_type1_id'], $row_PlaySystem['play_system']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_character_type['character_type1']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_character_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($character_type));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($character_type);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($character_type, 0);
      $row_character_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($character_type);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_UserLoginForm['user_id']; ?>">
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="NewCharacterSubmit" id="NewCharacterSubmit" value="Create character">
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="PlaySystemForm">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($UserLoginForm);

mysql_free_result($PlaySystem);

mysql_free_result($characters);

mysql_free_result($character_type);
?>


  <input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_UserLoginForm['user_id']; ?>">
```

That's the code that I think is the problem.  No matter who I'm logged in as when I hit submit, I only get a result of "1", which I think is returning a result of TRUE, but I need the actual numerical result to fill in the character_owner field so the users will only see the stuff they make.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it and here's how:

I created this query (I believe I'm using the correct terminology):

```html
mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_CharacterOwner = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.user_id = 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = '{$_SESSION['MM_Username']}')";
$CharacterOwner = mysql_query($query_CharacterOwner, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CharacterOwner = mysql_fetch_assoc($CharacterOwner);
$totalRows_CharacterOwner = mysql_num_rows($CharacterOwner);
```

I used an answer from a previous question regarding subqueries and changed the name to something I could remember.  In this case "CharacterOwner" because that's what it is tracking.  The table data needed to come from where the user data is stored and to check against the session variable.  This makes it persistent across pages.

Then a hidden field was created so the user won't be able to change it and much with the system, but it will still fill in the data.  It takes the user_login name that the logged in user creates and compares that against the other values in the table to give a numerical user_id value.  This makes it so the user can change their name if they want but not lose their data.

This is the code for the hidden field:

```html
<input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_CharacterOwner['user_id']; ?>">
```

When the form submits it will create the correct user_id value now in the characters table.